# Excel/VBA to Simplify Navigation to Specific Excel Cells

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I have several Excel sheets each containing volunteers' information cards (~150 different names). I want to create a navigation/summary sheet that contains only the names, that allows me to jump/go directly to a specific volunteer name (specific cell) located on a different sheet within the same document.
Selecting a name in the list or choosing from a dropdown menu on the summary sheet both are excellent options.

Appreciate any help I can get.

Here's the code I am using based on @Teasel instructions:

```
Sub ComboBox_Change()
    Dim Sheet1 As String
    Dim Sheet2 As String
    Dim A As String
    Dim PickList As String

    listNamesSheet = "Name of your sheet where names are"
    secondSheet = "Name of your sheet, where the control is"
    colName = "Header of the column where names are"
    controlName = "Name of your combobox"

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(listNamesSheet)
        'Go through the range where names are
        For Each nameInSheet In .Range(colName & "1:" & colName & .Cells(.Rows.Count, colName).End(xlUp).Row)
            'If the name is the one selected in the ComboBox
            If (nameInSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(secondSheet).DropDowns(controlName).List(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(secondSheet).DropDowns(controlName).Value)) Then
                'Activate the first sheet (have to if you want to select a range inside it)
                .Activate
                'Select the case where the name has been found
                .Range(nameInSheet.Address).Select
            End If
        Next nameInSheet
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim Sheet1 As String
    Dim Sheet2 As String
    Dim A As String
    Dim PickList As String

    listNamesSheet = "Name of the sheet where names are"
    secondSheet = "Name of the sheet where you ComboBox is"
    colName = "Header of the column where names are" 'ex: "A" if names are in column A
    controlName = "Name of your combobox"


    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(listNamesSheet)
        'Go through the range where all the names are
        For Each nameInSheet In .Range(colName & "1:" & colName & .Cells(.Rows.Count, colName).End(xlUp).Row)
            'Add it to the ComboBox
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(secondSheet).DropDowns(controlName).AddItem nameInSheet
        Next nameInSheet
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at HYPERLINK - either right clicking and manually entering a hyperlink in a cell, or using the HYPERLINK formula:  `=HYPERLINK("[Book1.xlsx]Sheet2!A1","Jump to Sheet2 A1.")`

Comment: is the name always in the same cell on those 150 Sheets? Then you Need a "for each sheet"-macro, which would be quite easy to do.

Comment: Hello Darren, no the 150 names are spread over 5 sheets so the name is not in the same cell number. But this formula is really good but require I edit the formula to match the right name/right cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Add a ComboBox to your sheet

**1. Activate the Developer Tab**

Go In **File** > **Options** > **Customize Ribbon** > Check **Developer** in the list.

[image: Activate Developer Tab]

**2. Add a ComboBox to your sheet**

In the Developer Tab go in **Insert** > **ComboBox**
[image: Add the ComboBox]

Then resize and place it however you want.

**3. Change the name of your ComboBox**

You can change the name of your ComboBox by selecting it and changing its name in the textbox (red rectangle on the screen).

[image: Change name of your ComboBox]

**4. Assign a macro to your ComboBox**

Right clic on your ComboBox and **Assign Macro...**

A window will appear. Choose the name of your function (left red rectangle on the screen) and then clic **New** as you can see on the screen.
[image: Assign macro to ComboBox]

You can now insert code to execute when the value of you ComboBox changes.

For you, insert the following code inside the function that has been created.

```
    Dim listNamesSheet As String
    Dim secondSheet As String
    Dim colName As String
    Dim controlName As String

    listNamesSheet = "Sheet1"
    secondSheet = "Sheet2"
    colName = "A"
    controlName = "PickList"

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(listNamesSheet)
        'Go through the range where names are
        For Each nameInSheet In .Range(colName & "1:" & colName & .Cells(.Rows.Count, colName).End(xlUp).Row)
            'If the name is the one selected in the ComboBox
            If (nameInSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(secondSheet).DropDowns(controlName).List(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(secondSheet).DropDowns(controlName).Value)) Then
                'Activate the first sheet (have to if you want to select a range inside it)
                .Activate
                'Select the case where the name has been found
                .Range(nameInSheet.Address).Select
            End If
        Next nameInSheet
    End With
```

---

### Populate your ComboBox with your names

**1. Add the Workbook_Open function to load your names when you launch the workbook**

Go back into your code (Alt+F11 or in Developer Tab > View Code) and add the following function after the code we added for the ComboBox.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
```

This is a function triggered when your workbook opens.

**2. Populate your ComboBox**

Add this code to the function.

```
Dim listNamesSheet As String
Dim secondSheet As String
Dim controlName As String
Dim colName As String

listNamesSheet = "Sheet1"
secondSheet = "Sheet2"
colName = "A" 'ex: "A" if names are in column A
controlName = "PickList"


With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(listNamesSheet)
    'Clear before adding new names
    For i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(secondSheet).DropDowns(controlName).ListCount To 1 Step -1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(secondSheet).DropDowns(controlName).RemoveItem i
    Next i

    'Go through the range where all the names are
    For Each nameInSheet In .Range(colName & "1:" & colName & .Cells(.Rows.Count, colName).End(xlUp).Row)
        'Add it to the ComboBox
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(secondSheet).DropDowns(controlName).AddItem nameInSheet
    Next nameInSheet
End With
```

---

### Adapt your code

Change the name of your first sheet in `listNamesSheet = "Sheet1"`.

Change the name of your second sheet in `secondSheet = "Sheet2"`.

Change the value of your column in `colName = "A"`.

Change the name of your ComboBox in `controlName = "PickList"`.

I didn't explain much about the code since it's commented so you must be able to understand but don't mind asking in the comments if something isn't clear.

Comment: Hello Teasel, this sounds like what am looking for as its dynamic, but its seems am not understating the instructions, for example how do I create a dropdown control? are you referring to VBA/Insert Module? Do I add it to the sheet containing the volunteers information or to the summary/first sheet? Also, how do I add a DropDown1_Change() function? I guess I will have to wait for more details as you said... But big thanks already

Comment: @Wiss Do not worry I'll explain everything necessary with printscreen. Just wait a few hours till I get home:)

Comment: @Wiss I made a pretty complete tutorial how to proceed, let me know if everything is ok. If it works please accept my answer it'd be kind. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank for the clear instructions! for some reason am getting error whenever I try the code, am getting "Script Out of Range" error or other error regarding "only comment expected after End Sub. Here's how my code look like:

Comment: @Wiss Can you be more specific about the error you're getting ? The the **Debug** button when the error appears, it should show you the line where you're getting an error.

Comment: The debug highlighted in yellow the following line:  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(listNamesSheet)

Comment: @Wiss I changed my code with the values you need to make your code work. When you tried to adapt my code you changed the name of the variable, not it's value so obviously you got an error.

Comment: Thanks for tweaking the code to compensate my ignorance :) But am getting error "Unable to get List Property of the Dropdown Class" and when I hit debug the following line is highlighted: If (nameInSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(secondSheet).DropDowns(controlName).List(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(secondSheet).DropDowns(controlName).Value)) Then

Comment: @Wiss Are you sure you added a **ComboBox** control and not another one ? What name did you give to your control ?

Comment: It works now, I was placing the third set of code not inside the Private Sub Workbook_Open() Funtion. It's working like magic! I noticed though that the names in the drop down are duplicated twice. Also what if my destination sheet (where the volunteers information are) are in 5 different sheets, can I add multiple sheets to the "secondsheet" argument? Big thanks already

Comment: Much appreciated! After trying the dropdown list and seeing that it's less practical to scroll down +150 names,  i would think its better if i could use the macro and assign it to a button and place that button next to each name in the summary sheet, when clicked it will pickup the right name (next to the button) and take me/jump to sheet/cell where that name resides (among 5 different sheets). I hope this is not very complicated to do, if it is i will stick to the dropdown list while removing duplicate names. Thank again

Comment: @Wiss I changed the code a little ; I clear the combobox before adding names so it doesn't add names twice it's uploaded every time your start your workbook. Instead of adding a lot of buttons next to your names I recommend you use a userForm and add a combobox (a combobox in a userform allows you to type inside of it and autocomplete with the elements in the list).

Comment: Thanks the code is now working as expected. I tried the userFrom as it seems a simpler idea, but whenever i run the code it show the box with an empty dropdown list, and whenever i start typing it doesn't fetch the list. Also i don't know how to place that userForm permanently in excel sheet.